# How to group fields of different type lists using JAVA 8?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, groupingby

Here the PHD student who is also a School teacher.
The common thing between these two objects is their name.
So I am filtering the data using their name.
Upto the code I wrote below in the MyMain class, I am able to filter the common records and get the student data.
But I also want the details of both Student and Teacher and set in the StudentTeacherMapper. Please help me to set the fields in StudentTeacherMapper class. Thank you.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PHDStudent {
                
    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private String grade;
    private int rank;
                
}
       
@Getter
@Setter
public class SCHLTeacher {
            
    private int teacherId;
    private String teacherName;
    private String place;
    private Long Salary;                
}
    
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentTeacherMapper {
        
    private int teacherId;
    private String teacherName;
    private String place;
    private Long Salary;
    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private String grade;
    private int rank;
    
}


public class MyMain {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<SCHLTeacher> teachList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<PHDStudent> studList = new ArrayList<>();

        mapStudentTeacherData(teachList, studList);
        
        List<PHDStudent> studentList = teachList.stream().flatMap(
                teach -> studList.stream().filter(predicate -> predicate.getStudentName().equals(teach.getTeacherName())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        StudentTeacherMapper mapper = new StudentTeacherMapper();
        //set data in mapper
        

    }

    private static void mapStudentTeacherData(List<SCHLTeacher> teachList, List<PHDStudent> studList) {
        SCHLTeacher teach1 = new SCHLTeacher();
        teach1.setPlace("Mumbai");
        teach1.setSalary(100000L);
        teach1.setTeacherId(11);
        teach1.setTeacherName("Ms.Grace444");
        SCHLTeacher teach2 = new SCHLTeacher();
        teach2.setPlace("Delhi");
        teach2.setSalary(160000L);
        teach2.setTeacherId(22);
        teach2.setTeacherName("Mr.Paul123");
        
        teachList.add(teach1);
        teachList.add(teach2);

        PHDStudent stud1 = new PHDStudent();
        stud1.setGrade("A");
        stud1.setRank(1);
        stud1.setStudentId(11);
        stud1.setStudentName("Ms.Grace444");
        PHDStudent stud2 = new PHDStudent();
        stud2.setGrade("C");
        stud2.setRank(44);
        stud2.setStudentId(22);
        stud2.setStudentName("Mr.Paul123");
        PHDStudent stud3 = new PHDStudent();
        stud3.setGrade("B");
        stud3.setRank(12);
        stud3.setStudentId(45);
        stud3.setStudentName("Mr.X22");
        
        studList.add(stud1);
        studList.add(stud2);
        studList.add(stud3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `constructor` in `StudentTeacherMapper` class for accommodating both `PHDStudent` and `SCHLTeacher` class like below:

```
public StudentTeacherMapper(PHDStudent student, SCHLTeacher teacher) {
    if (teacher != null) {
        this.teacherId = teacher.getTeacherId();
        this.teacherName = teacher.getTeacherName();
        this.place = teacher.getPlace();
        this.salary = teacher.getSalary();
    }
    if (student != null) {
        this.studentId = student.getStudentId();
        this.studentName = student.getStudentName();
        this.grade = student.getGrade();
        this.rank = student.getRank();
    }
}
```

In the `main` class, after the `mapStudentTeacherData(teachList, studList)`, do as follows:

```
List<StudentTeacherMapper> mappers = new ArrayList<>();

teachList.forEach(x -> {
    List<PHDStudent> students = studList
            .stream()
            .filter(y -> x.getTeacherName()
                    .equals(y.getStudentName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(students.size() > 0) {
        students.stream().forEach(z -> {
            StudentTeacherMapper mapper = new StudentTeacherMapper(z,x);
            mappers.add(mapper);
        });
    }
});

// do what you want with the mappers
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked for my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Create constructor:

```java
public StudentTeacherMapper(SCHLTeacher teacher, PHDStudent student){
    StudentTeacherMapper mapper = new StudentTeacherMapper();
    mapper.setTeacherId(teacher.getTeacherId());
    mapper.setPlace(teacher.getPlace());
    mapper.setTeacherName(teacher.getTeacherName());
    mapper.setSalary(teacher.getSalary());
    mapper.setStudentName(student.getStudentName());
    mapper.setStudentId(student.getStudentId());
    mapper.setGrade(student.getGrade());
    mapper.setRank(student.getRank());
}
```

and collect mappers using `Stream API`:

```java
List<StudentTeacherMapper> mappers = teachList
    .stream()
    .flatMap(teach ->
         studList
             .stream()
             .filter(student -> student.getStudentName().equals(teach.getTeacherName()))
             .findFirst()
             .map(student -> Stream.of(new StudentTeacherMapper(teach, student)))
             .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to put two constructors in your `StudentTeacherMapper` class.

- the first is for students and teachers
- the second is just for students (your example shows you have a superset of students).  This one has default values for the teachers data. Getters and setters not shown.

```
class StudentTeacherMapper {
    private int teacherId;
    private String teacherName;
    private String place;
    private long Salary = 0L;
    private int studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private String grade;
    private int rank;
    
    public StudentTeacherMapper(int teacherId, String teacherName,
            String place, long salary, int studentId,
            String studentName, String grade, int rank) {
        
        this.teacherId = teacherId;
        this.teacherName = teacherName;
        this.place = place;
        Salary = salary;
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public StudentTeacherMapper(int studentId, String studentName,
            String grade, int rank) {
        this(-1, "No teacher assigned", "No place defined", 0L, studentId, studentName,
                grade, rank);
    }   
}
```

Next, make a map of the teachers for associating them with the students. The presumes that there are no duplicate teacher names (else that would result in other complications).  One idea is to have a unique ID that applies to both teachers and students.

```
Map<String, SCHLTeacher> teachers = teachList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(SCHLTeacher::getName, t->t));
```

Now use that map to coordinate the two.  The constructor called depends on the existence of the teacher.  The results are in the `stList`

```
        
List<StudentTeacherMapper> stList =
        studList.stream().map(s -> {
            SCHLTeacher t = teachers.get(s.getStudentName());
            return t != null ?
                    new StudentTeacherMapper(t.getTeacherId(),
                            t.getTeacherName(), t.getPlace(),
                            t.getSalary(), s.getStudentId(),
                            s.getStudentName(), s.getGrade(),
                            s.getRank()) :
                    new StudentTeacherMapper(s.getStudentId(),
                            s.getStudentName(), s.getGrade(),
                            s.getRank());
        }).toList(); // or collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A couple of suggestions.

- One as I mentioned before, a common ID for students and teachers would be useful.
- Why have the names in twice in the mapper class.  It seems only one is necessary since it is the name used to associate the students and teachers.